# Fluent Cassandra filtering based on more than one column

Tags: c#, filtering, fluentcassandra

I am trying to use your Fluent Cassandra for one of our project. But our project requires that the results be shown in paged manner as well as filtered on the basis of more than one column.
I have seen Nick Berardi's post for filtering based on one column(last_name).

```
    var results = familyname.Get(startKey: "key", keyCount: 30, family => family["last_name"] == "Smith")

    .Take(5)
    .FirstOrDefault()

    .AsDynamic()
```

How to achieve the same for 2 columns e.g. "first_name" and"middle_name". 
Also will it be possible to translate the SQL:

```
select user where "first_name" like %Nick% AND/OR "last_name" like %Berardi%
```

to work in Fluent Cassandra. I am really getting stuck. Your help will be highly appreciated.